# For positive and self-adjoint $C$ and $\lambda > 0$, show that $\sup_v \langle v, (C+\lambda I)^{-1}v\rangle \le \sup_v\frac{\|v\|^2}{\lambda}.$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

For positive and self-adjoint $C$ and $\lambda > 0$, show that

$$\sup_v \langle v, (C+\lambda I)^{-1}v\rangle \le \sup_v\frac{\|v\|^2}{\lambda},$$
with $\sup_v \|v\|^2 \le \kappa$.

My try: CBS yields
$$\sup_v \langle v, (C+\lambda I)^{-1}v\rangle \le \sup_v \|v\|^2\|(C+\lambda I)^{-1}\|,$$
so I guess one must show that $\|(C+\lambda I)^{-1}\| \le \frac{1}{ \lambda}$. Now,

\begin{align*}
\|C+\lambda I\|^2 &= \|C\| + 2\langle C, \lambda I\rangle + \lambda^2, \\
\implies \|C+\lambda I\| &\ge \lambda.
\end{align*}

One has the trivial bound $\|A\|^{-1} \le \|A\|^{-1}$ but unless I am missing something I am stuck here as I do not know how to relate the bound on $C+\lambda I$ to its inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\|(C+\lambda I)v\|\,\|v\|\ge \langle (C+\lambda I)v,v\rangle \ge \langle Cv,v\rangle +\lambda\|v\|^2\ge \lambda\|v\|^2$$
Therefore
$$\|(C+\lambda I)v\|\ge \lambda\|v\|$$
This implies that the operator $C+\lambda I$ is injective and has the closed range. This operator is surjective as $${\rm Im}\,(C+\lambda I)=[\ker (C+\lambda I)]^\perp=\{0\}^\perp =\mathcal{H}$$ Let $u=(C+\lambda I)v.$ Then
$$\|u\|\ge \lambda\|(C+\lambda I)^{-1}u\|$$ Hence $\|(C+\lambda I)^{-1}\|\le {1\over \lambda}.$ Finally
$$\langle u, (C+\lambda I)^{-1}u\rangle\le \|(C+\lambda I)^{-1}\|\,\|u\|^2\le {\|u\|^2\over \lambda} $$

Comment: Thank you very much!